# Collaboration in AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a question regarding google app engine. 
Let us say you are working on a project and you want to have 5 developers on it. 
How will the collaboration be carried out? SVN, CVS - anything of that sort for the google app engine? 
The collaboration is for a private project.

Comment: google appengine doesn't care how you manage your source code. use whatever works for your team.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After adding them to your application in the Permission Pane of the admin console, developers will be able to deploy new application version using `appcfg.py` command.

People usually create multiple application version for each developer, or multiple applications if they want to isolate development data from production.

Each application version is addressable through: `versionname.appid.appspot.com`

Answer (score 2):

You can use whatever Version Control System you want, and host it where ever you want. Google App Engine doesn't restrict you to using any specific ones, nor have one integrated (why would it?).

I personally use Git (and eventually GitHub) for my App Engine project, but I could have used any other- it's entirely what you think your team would work best with.

Comment: On github - your source can be viewed by anybody right? This is not an open source project. This is my scenario.

Comment: Yes and no. If you go with a free account, you can only make public repositories. If you go with *any* paid account, you can make private repositories as well. Many businesses use GitHub for hosting private repositories (I worked for one that did). GitHub is also not the only option for hosting private repositories for Git- it's also pretty trivial to set up your *own* repository on a system you control. At the very least you should use a Distributed VCS like Git, not a centralized one like SVN/CVS.